# Rails how to show on one page existing associated records AND permit new associated record input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, has-many

My main record is a Plate (as in license plate).
It can have many Translations (meanings or comments).
On one page I want to:
1)show a plate record and allow users to rate the plate
2)show all existing translation records and allow users to vote for one
3)allow the user to create a new translation record
I am using form_for the Plate, and fields_for for the existing translation records.
My research suggests there should be a way to do this, but my code is not delivering a blank form.  Currently I am trying a second fields_for loop.
At the moment, I am just focused on my rendered forms page, I have not gotten to processing the input yet. 
The final fields_for which is meant to display a blank box for a new translation input, is instead showing the last existing translation.
I will appreciate any suggestions.
Below is my edit form: _rate_or_vote.html.erb

```
<!-- app/views/plates/_rate_or_vote.html.erb -->
<%= form_for(@plate) do |f| %>

<% if @plate.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@plate.errors.count, "error") %>
      prohibited this plate from being updated:</h2>
    <ul>
      <% @plate.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

<h1>Rate the Plate</h1>

<span class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :input_rating, "Your Plate Rating" %>
  <%= f.select :input_rating, options_for_select(RATINGS)  %>
</span>&nbsp&nbsp
<span class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :rating, "Average Rating" %>
  <%= f.text_field :rating , :value => (number_with_precision(f.object.rating, :precision => 2) || 0) %>
</span>&nbsp&nbsp
<span class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :plate_number, "Plate Number" %>
  <%= f.text_field :plate_number %>
</span>&nbsp&nbsp
<span class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :state, "State" %>
  <%= f.text_field :state, class: "form-control" %>
</span><br><br>
<span style="background-color:#DCDCDC; color:#000000; font-style: normal; font-family:Georgia;">
  Contributor</span>
<span style="border:1px solid black;padding:3pt;">
  <%= @plate.user.full_name %></span>&nbsp&nbsp
<span class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :plate_image, "Plate Image File" %>
  <%= f.file_field :plate_image %>
</span><br><br>

<h1>Existing Translations and/or Comments - You can vote for one</h1>
<!-- %= f.fields_for :translations do |ff| %-->
<%= f.fields_for :translations, @plate.translations do |ff| %>
<span>Click this box to vote for this translation:</span>&nbsp
<span><%= check_box_tag "translation_ids[]", :id %></span>&nbsp&nbsp
<span><%= ff.label "Current votes" %>
  <%= ff.text_field :votes, :value => (number_to_percentage(ff.object.votes / ( @plate.translation_votes.nonzero? || 1 ) * 100,
  precision: 0)) %>
</span>&nbsp&nbsp
<span style="background-color:#DCDCDC; color:#000000; font-style: normal; font-family:Georgia;">
  Contributor</span>
<span style="border:1px solid black;padding:3pt;">
  <%= ff.object.user.full_name %></span><br><br>
<span>Translation and/or Comment</span><br>
<span>
<%= ff.text_area :meaning, :cols => 60, :rows => 10  %>
</span><br><br>
<% end %>

<h1>Offer a new Translation and/or Comment</h1>
<!-- %= f.fields_for :translations do |ff| %-->
<%= f.fields_for :translations, @plate.translations do |fff| %>
  <div>
<!-- %= fff.label :meaning, "Translation" %-->
    <%= fff.text_field :meaning %>
  </div><br><br>
<% end %>

<%= f.submit "Save and/or Return", :name => "update", class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so `@plate.translations` is the set of current translations that are already on the plate.

If you want a fields-for section for a new one... you have to actually build a new one.

eg:

```
<%= f.fields_for :translations, [@plate.translations.build] do |fff| %>
  <div>
    <%= fff.text_field :meaning %>
  </div><br><br>
<% end %>
```